# Powershell script with a CSV to get objectID from DisplayName

Tags: azure, powershell, csv

I want to make a new CSV file containing only ObjectID from a CSV file with a list of Computer name (DisplayName)

```
connect-azuread
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Tools\PCname.csv
foreach ($DisplayName in $csv){
    $ObejctID = get-AzureADDevice -Filter "DisplayName eq '$._DisplayName'" | Select ObjectID 
}
$ObejctID
$Content.objectID | Out-File 'C:\Tools\BulkObjectID.csv'
```

I have the following error from the ISE :

```
***get-AzureADDevice : Le terme «get-AzureADDevice» n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande, fonction, fichier de script ou 
programme exécutable. Vérifiez l'orthographe du nom, ou si un chemin d'accès existe, vérifiez que le chemin d'accès est correct et 
réessayez.
Au caractère Ligne:11 : 17
+     $ObejctID = get-AzureADDevice -Filter "DisplayName eq '$._Display ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-AzureADDevice:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException***
```

Can Anyone help me please ?

Comment: Please run your non-English error messages through a service such as Google Translate and (at least _also_) include the English translation.

Comment: In the abstract, the error message implies that either the module that contains the `get-AzureADDevice` command isn't loaded in your session or that you misspelled the command name.

Comment: [`Get-AzureADDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddevice) comes with the `AzureAD` module. You need to investigate if it is installed, via `Get-Module -ListAvailable`, and, if so, why it isn't [auto-loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading). If it is installed in a nonstandard location, you may need to call [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) explicitly first.

Answer (score 0):

aside from getting your Get-AzureADDevice working. doesn't look like you're adding anything to the list. I would do something like this. Create an empty array ObjectID. Then in for Foreach you add your elements to the array. After your foreach you call the array and pipe it out to export-csv.

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Tools\PCname.csv
$ObjectID=@()
foreach ($DisplayName in $csv){
    $ObejctID += get-AzureADDevice -Filter "DisplayName eq '$._DisplayName'" | Select ObjectID 
}
$ObejctID
$ObjectID | export-csv 'C:\Tools\BulkObjectID.csv'
```